# Jenkins windows batch command copy files under the folder which versioning is latest

Tags: jenkins

the folder structure of source path is:
C:\test\2.4

- 20231201_2.4_1101

  - installerA.exe
  - installerB.exe
- 20231211_2.4_1120

  - installerA.exe
  - installerB.exe

Destination folder structure:
C:\install\software
- installerA.exe
- installerB.exe

What should be the windows command to copy latest installerA.exe and installerB.exe from source folder C:\test\2.4 to destination C:\install\software?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find latest folder and store it to variable and then using variable prepare path and copy file to destination.

The batch file.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir "C:\test\2.4" /b /ad-h /t:c /o-d') DO (SET a=%%i)
XCOPY "C:\test\2.4\%a%\installerA.exe" "C:\install\software" /Y
XCOPY "C:\test\2.4\%a%\installerB.exe" "C:\install\software" /Y
```